# Filter for column value if another column contains a value

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, conditional-statements

Essentially I would like to filter a column if another column contains a value. Here is an example:

```
my_df <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
           y = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)) 
> my_df
  x y
1 1 1
2 1 2
3 1 3
4 2 4
5 2 5
6 2 6
```

Let's filter `x!=1` if and only if `y!=1`. Here is my expected result:

```
  x y
1 1 1
2 2 4
3 2 5
4 2 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a `group_by` `filter` here

```
library(dplyr)
my_df %>%
   group_by(x) %>% 
   filter(if(any(y == 1)) y == 1 else TRUE)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   x [2]
#      x     y
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1
#2     2     4
#3     2     5
#4     2     6
```

Or if it doesn't needs to be group by

```
my_df %>%
   filter( (x == 1 & y == 1)|(x !=1))
```

---

Or with `subset`

```
subset(my_df,  (x == 1 & y == 1)|(x !=1))
#  x y
#1 1 1
#4 2 4
#5 2 5
#6 2 6
```

Or

```
subset(my_df,  (x == 1 & y == 1)|(x !=1 & y != 1))
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. When would a group by be necessary?

Comment: @Ali It is when you are checking whether for each unique value of 'x' the condition for 'y' would be met.  Here, your conddition is only for a particular value of x, so group by is not needed